# What is CSS injection and how to prevent it?

Tags: css, security, penetration-testing

I have heard my friend talking about this vulnerability called "CSS Injections" However, I have no idea what this is and as soon as I heard it I thought, how could one possibly do any malicious activity or an attack using CSS?

So I wanted to know what is this "CSS Injections" vulnerability and how does one prevent it.

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/css-injection-exploitation/

Comment: This better to be asked on the site [security.se]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***What is it?***

CSS injection means that an attacker manages to upload malicious CSS code to your website which will run on your visitors' browsers.

***Is it dangerous?***

Writing this in 2022, ***NO***, CSS injection is almost not affecting anyone since browsers have overcome this, but **note** that some users using old browsers may get affected by this.

***Should I do something?***

***Yes*** you should, even though it is not currently a real risk, you should prevent attackers from injecting your website with malicious **CSS** and **JavaScript**, **JavaScript** is very important because some exploits were batched recently and most users didn't update their browsers to the latest version yet.

***How to protect?***

You should always **filter user input** from malicious injections but an extra layer of protection is:

a solution to all this is using ***CSP* Header**  (**Content-Security-Policy**) which allows you to prevent browsers from executing malicious code on your website.

in **apache** *htaccess* file add the following but **mod_headers** should be enabled

```
Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self';script-src 'self';style-src 'self'; object-src 'none'; frame-ancestors 'none'; form-action 'self';  base-uri 'self';"
```

***Note that*** you can't use the code above if you use **CSS** or **JavaScript** from another domain.

For more info and to understand what each word in the code does visit [MDN CSP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy)

***EDIT:***

The simplest example of **CSS** injection is when an attacker manages to inject your website with a **CSS** code that loads an external asset such as in backgrounds and those assets are payloads, luckily most browsers have overcome such vulnerability.

```
background: url(http://somehackerdomain.com/payload...)
```

Another simple example of **CSS** injection which still affects all modern browsers is that in case your website **JavaScript** uses a **CSS** property value, then the attacker could set a new value for this property as a JavaScript code which may steal cookies, etc.

Those are only some of the simple examples.

For more about CSS injection see [C-SHARP-CORNER CSS Injection](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/css-injection-exploitation/)

A third layer of protection to protect cookies is to use ***HttpOnly*** which prevents **JavaScript** from accessing them. for more about **HttpOnly** visit [HttpOnly](https://owasp.org/www-community/HttpOnly)

Comment: Yes, but how can CSS code be malicious? please edit your answer to include that and an example of a CSS injection.

Comment: I added two simple examples. I hope they help clear things up.

Comment: @yherbawi very good! I also suggest this for more information: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/css-injection-exploitation/

Comment: @LaaouatniAnas thanks, I added the link to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

CSS Injection occurs when an attacker injects malicious CSS code into your web application but there is not any security impact for this vulnerability, but it may lead to displaying harmful advertisements on your website. You can prevent it by input validation and implementing security headers like content-security-policy (CSP).