# Am I vulnerable to CSS injections or other vulnerabilities?

Tags: php, css, laravel

On my website, there are "communities". I want to give communities the ability to have custom styling on their community pages. Like subreddits on reddit.com for those who are familiar. For reference, I use Laravel as my development framework, but I don't think this is very important when it comes to this question.

In order to achieve this, I allow users to submit a custom stylesheet (in a textarea input).

First I validate this like any other user input, then I make sure there are no external URLs (since this appears to be the way CSS injections work):

```
    $text = $request->get('styles');
    
    $hasExternalURL = strpos($text, 'http') !== false || strpos($text, 'www.') !== false;
    
    if($hasExternalURL){
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Error: No external URLs allowed.'], 404);
    }
```

then, I make sure that the user input is a valid stylesheet. So I use the CSS validator API provided by w3c (https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/api.html) for this.

```
    $response = Http::get('https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator', [
        'text' => $text,
        'output' => 'soap12',
    ]);
    $headersArray = $response->headers();
    
    $validationErrorCount = $headersArray['x-w3c-validator-errors'][0];
    
    if ($validationErrorCount) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Errors found in styles. Try using a CSS validator before submitting styles.'], 404);
    }
```

If the user input is indeed valid CSS, then I save the input as a `.css` file and I load this in the header of my website for those communities.

I'm wondering if this is enough to prevent vulnerabilities. There isn't much information out there on allowing users to upload their own stylesheets.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is CSS injection and how to prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70558753/what-is-css-injection-and-how-to-prevent-it)

Comment: Wow. CSS injection is a thing? Wow.

Comment: @ADyson I've read this before but I still want to know if my solution would work.

Comment: Well if it successfully prevents urls being injected then it's one line of defence. You should probably also take the other steps mentioned in that link, too